# .class expected error in my method and sometimes missing return statement error

Tags: java

I fairly new to java and i don't know why this piece of code isn't compiling. Its also sometimes isn't return my result. Any suggestions?

```
public static char isPrime(int x)
        {

            for(int y=2;y<x;y++)
                char result = 'r';
                    if(x%y==0)
                    result = 't';
                    else
                    result = 'f';

            return result;
        }
```

or

```
public static char isPrime(int x)
        {
            char result = 'r';
            for(int y=2;y<x;y++)

                    if(x%y==0)
                    result = 't';
                    else
                    result = 'f';

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: where should i add them?

Comment: You should return a `boolean`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put brackets in your `for` statement otherwise it will just take the first line

your error is likely that `y` is out of scope when you use it

you also have to declare `result` outside your for loop, for the same reason of scope

```
public static char isPrime(int x)
{
    char result = 'r';

    for(int y=2;y<x;y++)
    {  
        if(x%y==0)
            result = 't';
        else
            result = 'f';
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use braces, your code would look like this:

```
public static char isPrime(int x) {
    for(int y=2;y<x;y++) {
        char result = 'r';
    }
    if(x%y==0) {
        result = 't';
    }
    else {
        result = 'f';
    }

    return result;
}
```

as you can see, the variables y and result are only visible in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

[The braces after a for-statement or if-statement are optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html), but there may only be one statement immediately following the line.

In the first case, `result` is only ever defined in the scope of the `for`.  If you try to reference it elsewhere, it won't exist (leading to an issue with scoping).

Your second case will, surprisingly, work - each statement following either a for or an if is its own statement.

For readability and reliability, though, it is **strongly** encouraged to use braces around your for-statement and if-statement.  Otherwise, your code will be very brittle.